# I am making a simon says compiler game in java and I'm having two issues

Tags: java

I am making a simon says game in java like the title says. This isn't the finished product but I'm trying to make it so that if the user repeats what the program tells them, it puts it in an array list and compares the color list and guess list however even if the list has the same contents, the if statement sees it as unequal.

I am also wondering if you can clear a line in the compiler so that the colors disappear.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimonSays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> Colors = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> guesses = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
            int k = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
            if (k == 0) {
                Colors.add("Red");
                }
                if (k == 1) {
                Colors.add("Blue");
                }
                if (k == 2) {
                Colors.add("Yellow");
                }
                if (k == 3) {
                Colors.add("Green");
                }
        
        }
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println(Colors); 
        
        for(int g = 0; g < 4; g++) {
        String guess = input.nextLine();
        guesses.add(guess);
        }
        System.out.println(guesses);
        if (guesses == Colors) {
            System.out.println("Well done!");
            input.close();
         }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not correct! You lose!");
            input.close(); 
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now you can ask a question about one of the issues.

Comment: `guesses == Colors` is not how you check if two lists have the exact same contents in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is how your testing for equality. `==` is for primitives and testing if 2 objects are the exact same object in memory.  For testing data equality, you should use `.equals()`

I cleaned up your code a bit:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> colors = Arrays.asList("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green");
    List<String> patternToMatch = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> guesses = new ArrayList<>();
    int lengthOfPattern = 4;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfPattern; i++) {
        int k = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        patternToMatch.add(colors.get(k%4));
    }
    
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        
        System.out.println(patternToMatch); 
        
        for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfPattern; i++) {
            String guess = input.nextLine();
            guesses.add(guess);
        }
        
        System.out.println(guesses);
        if (guesses.equals(patternToMatch)) {
            System.out.println("Well done!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not correct! You lose!");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You should create a Color enum (or piggy back on the one from AWT). If the user doesn't get the case correct, the equality will fail as "blue" isn't the same as "Blue".